# How to upgrade Visual Studio 2012 workflows to Visual studio 2013 workflows?

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, visual-studio-2013

For using the Visual studio 2013 .Net Framework 4.5 workflows**, do I need to install Workflow Manager?

When upgraded from VS 2012 Framework 3.5 to VS 2013 4.5 Framework, I got the warning message as "System.workflows.* are deprecated. Instead, Use System.Activities.*". What are the steps we need to follow?  Can you please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

System.workflows belongs to WF 3(SharePoint 2010 uses WF 3.5), SharePoint support Windows Workflow Foundation 3 and Windows Workflow Foundation 4(require Workflow Manager),[check here for more details](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/governance/install-and-configure-workflow-for-sharepoint-server).

If you need migrate SharePoint 2010 workflow to SharePoint 2013, you could ignore the warning, when you create SharePoint 2010 workflow in VS2013(for SharePoint 2013 solution), you would see below attribute defined in wokflow calss.
[image]

You could configure Workflow Manager and re-design your SharePoint 2010 workflow to SharePoint 2013 workflow also.